# why useReducer is returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using useReducer to mange my states in a form and everything is working perfectly fine until I submit the fine on form submission I am logging all my state values in the console but it returns all values as undefined as null except for the last one

**Console Output:**

```
{product_id: undefined, product_name: undefined, produuct_price: '55'}
product_id: undefined
product_name: undefined
produuct_price: "55"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I dont know why its happening because all state binding is working perfectly fine and if there is some problem why it is returning last value correctly:

```
import "./ProductForm.css";
import { useReducer } from "react";

const ProductForm = () => {
  const initialState = {
    product_id: "",
    product_name: "",
    product_quantity: 0,
    product_description: "",
    product_type: "",
    product_valid: "false",
    product_price: 0,
    product_title: "",
    product_image: "",
  };
  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === "id") {
      return { product_id: action.value };
    } else if (action.type === "name") {
      return { product_name: action.value };
    } else if (action.type === "title") {
      return { product_title: action.value };
    } else if (action.type === "price") {
      return { product_price: action.value };
    } else if (action.type === "image") {
      return { product_image: action.value };
    } else if (action.type === "description") {
      return { product_discription: action.value };
    } else if (action.type === "type") {
      return { product_type: action.value };
    }
  };
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const obj = {
      product_id: state.product_id,
      product_name: state.product_name,
      produuct_price: state.product_price,
    };
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Product id</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          value={state.product_id}
          onChange={(e) => dispatch({ type: "id", value: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Product Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          value={state.product_name}
          onChange={(e) => dispatch({ type: "name", value: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Product Price</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          value={state.product_price}
          onChange={(e) => dispatch({ type: "price", value: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-4">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ProductForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to return other field values too from the `state`, each time as below

```
 const reducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === "id") {
      return { ...state, product_id: action.value };
    } else if (action.type === "name") {
      return { ...state, product_name: action.value };
    }
    // likewise for all
  };
```

so it returns all the fields in the `state` with the updated field value, other wise the state will always be the last updated value which in your case is the `produuct_price`...

you can check by logging the `state` from your current code and will have is just this below, as it is the last updated value ...

`{produuct_price: "55"}`